# Customized payment integration for only amount

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, review

I want to take only amount from customers not order information and pass that amount to Place Order button.

I tried On click of **Place Order** button I have called `review.save();` function. I am not understanding how to pass amount value and do successful transaction?

`skin\frontend\default\new_design\js\opcheckout.js` - I tried alerting this file but everything went in vain.

Can anyone explain why this function is used `review.save()` ?